# Can anybody help me with the syntax of setters and getters?

Tags: c#, vb.net

i have set mName, mContact and memail as my variables.. and i want to use them in setter and getters.. can any body help me doing so? only want to know the syntax..

regards..

Comment: You've tagged VB.net and C# - which one?

Comment: he tagged it as "vb.net-to-c#" but it looks like skaffman changed it

Answer (score 4):

If you have an existing private variable and you want to expose some public properties then you should do the following:

```
private string mName;
public string Name
{
   get
   {
      return mName;
   }

   set
   {
      mName = value;
   }
}
```

You could also avoid the need for the internal private variable by using a Automatic Properties:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

As JWL has pointed out in the comments you can also set modifiers on getters and setters. Valid modifiers are `private`/`internal`/`protected`.

```
public string Name { get; private set; }
public string Name { protected get; set; }
```

Comment: In addition to public string Name { get; set; } you can specify the scope for the setter or the getter with public string Name { get; private/internal/protected set; }

Answer (score 3):

### Visual Studio Tip:

Set your cursor inside of the field (`Private int _i;`) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> This will create the property accessors for you :)

Answer (score 0):

It is also a good practice to implement checking, whether setting up the private variable is really necessary. Like this>

```
private string mName;
public string Name
{
   get
   {
      return mName;
   }

   set
   {
      if ( value != mName )
      {
           mName = value;
      }
   }
}
```